# Difference between a sparse matrix and a dense matrix for matrix multiplications in python

Tags: python, matrix, sparse-matrix

I would like to calculate the first derivative of a 2d-function in Python. For that purpose I wrote the following script:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import scipy.sparse as scspar

r_num = 10000
r_vec = np.linspace(-10, 10, r_num)
X_mat, Y_mat = np.meshgrid(r_vec, r_vec)

x_square = lambda X, Y: np.exp(-np.power(X, 2)/2-np.power(Y, 2)/2)
dh = abs(r_vec[1]-r_vec[0])

A = (np.eye(r_num)*(-30)+np.eye(r_num, k=-1)*(16)+np.eye(r_num, k=1)*(16)-np.eye(r_num, k=2)-np.eye(r_num, k=-2))/(12*dh*dh)
C = (np.eye(r_num)*(-30)+np.eye(r_num, k=-1)*(16)+np.eye(r_num, k=1)*(16)-np.eye(r_num, k=-2)-np.eye(r_num, k=2))/(12*dh*dh)
B = scspar.csc_matrix((np.eye(r_num)*-30+np.eye(r_num, k=-1)*16+np.eye(r_num, k=1)*16-np.eye(r_num, k=-2)-np.eye(r_num, k=2))/(12*dh*dh))
T = x_square(X_mat, Y_mat)

plt.imshow(A-B)
plt.show()

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X_mat, Y_mat, T*B+(T.transpose()*B).transpose())
plt.show()
```

Now matrix `A` and `B` are equal, except that one is defined as sparse, and the other one as dense. But when replacing the line

```
T*B+(T.transpose()*B).transpose()
```

with

```
T*A+(T.transpose()*A).transpose()
```

the result is changed significantly. Why?

Answer (score 0):

If they are the same, they should have the same result. Thus, you can conclude that you made a mistake somewhere.

From the [scipy docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html):

> Despite their similarity to NumPy arrays, it is **strongly discouraged**
>   to use NumPy functions directly on these matrices because NumPy may
>   not properly convert them for computations, leading to unexpected (and
>   incorrect) results. If you do want to apply a NumPy function to these
>   matrices, first check if SciPy has its own implementation for the
>   given sparse matrix class, or **convert the sparse matrix to a NumPy**
>   **array** (e.g. using the toarray() method of the class) first before
>   applying the method.

Indeed, the docs tell us to not use numpy functions on these sparse matrices, and instead use [specialized functions from scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html#matrix-vector-product) to operate on the sparse matrices.

Comment: As far as I can see I set `B=scspar.csc_matrix(A)`, thus they should be equal?

Comment: I don't have direct experience, but the equality operator could be overloaded. I just checked, yes, it seems so: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/69170135bd5e5b1e9b4d712ca9a4307283780f14/scipy/sparse/base.py#L309

Comment: And that means?

Comment: @arc_lupus That means that the equality operator doesn't mean the same thing that it usually does -- it's overridden by the `__eq__` function. You can see in the source code that it converts both arguments (to the equality operator `=`) to a sparse matrix before comparison. I think I used a misnomer earlier; the term for such behavior is method "overriding".

Comment: I am never using the `=`-operator, I am directly converting `A` into `B`?

Comment: Sorry, I'm being inaccurate again, I meant `==` for equality.